# Package installation failing in Rstudio, how to determine what is wrong?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to install rmarkdown in Rstudio. Installation fails because it is trying to instal into the wrong folder, which doesn't exist. Why is it trying to install into the folder .Rprofile/win-library/3.2, eventhough i've configured it to install into R/win-library/3.2?

I get the same error if i don't specify the lib parameter for install.packages.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "c:/Users/ako/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" "C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.1/library"    
> install.packages("rmarkdown",lib="c:/Users/ako/Documents/R/win-library/3.2")
trying URL 'https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-07-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/rmarkdown_0.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1310297 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

Error in install.packages : path[1]="c:\Users\ako\Documents\.Rprofile\win-library\3.2": The system cannot find the path specified
```

**Update**: something odd is going on with libPaths, changing libPaths doesn't work now:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "c:/Users/ako/Documents/.Rprofile/win-library/3.2" "C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.1/library"            
> file.exists("c:/Users/ako/Documents/R/win-library/3.2")
[1] TRUE
> .libPaths("c:/Users/ako/Documents/R/win-library/3.2")
> .libPaths()
[1] "c:/Users/ako/Documents/.Rprofile/win-library/3.2" "C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.1/library"
```

Debugging libPaths is see the following:

```
....
Browse[2]> 
debug: new <- Sys.glob(path.expand(new))
Browse[2]> new
[1] "c:/Users/ako/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"
Browse[2]> 
debug: paths <- unique(normalizePath(c(new, .Library.site, .Library), 
    "/"))
Browse[2]> c(new, .Library.site, .Library)
[1] "c:/Users/ako/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" "C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/R-32~1.1/library"        
Browse[2]> normalizePath(c(new, .Library.site, .Library), 
+ "/")
[1] "c:/Users/ako/Documents/.Rprofile/win-library/3.2" "C:/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.1/library"
```

So normalizePath replaces the folder /R/ with /.Rprofile/. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: That's bizarre! You might try `debugonce(utils:::install.packages)` and then try it again--much of `install.packages` is written in R so it might be possible to ascertain where the errant path is being introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by reinstalling R, RRO and RStudio into folders that don't contain spaces...